# How can I make the input form smaller?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My input form's width is too long. How can I make this shorter?
This is my HTML code:

```
</div>                          
  <form method="POST" action="/post/10/">
    <input type="hidden">
      <div class="form-group">
        <tr>
          <th><label for="id_body">Add a Comment:</label>
          </th>
          <td>
            <textarea name="body" cols="40" rows="4" class="form-control form-control-sm"
              placeholder="Comment here ..." size="1" required id="id_body">
            </textarea>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </div> 
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Comment</button>   
    </form>
</div>
```

And this is how it looks like:

[image: This is how my input form look like1]

Comment: You could place it within a container set to a specific size, or just style the textarea's width

Comment: You forgot to close your `<input type="hidden"` on line 3 change it to `<input type="hidden">`

Comment: The HTML is very invalid. It starts with a closing `</div>` without an opening `<div>`, there's a hidden input that's not closed. There's a table row with no table... All of this could be affecting the CSS, since CSS is applied to whatever DOM the browser comes up with.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I fixed that `<div>` tag, but I don't know how to remove the `textarea` because `I'm using forms.Textarea()` in Django. How can I remove that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve what you want:

1. Add a sizing class supplied by BS itself: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/

2. Add a custom class to the textarea input (i.e. "textarea-w") and then add the width you need in the css file:

```
.textarea-w {
    width: ...;
}
```

Comment: That works, but now the position of my input form is next to the post content. I want it to be below my post content.

Comment: Try adding "col-12" to the post's div and then change its with a sizing class

Comment: No worries mate : )

Answer (score 0):

Change cols value in `textarea` ex. cols="20"

```
     <td>
        <textarea name="body" cols="20" rows="4" class="form-control form-control-sm"
          placeholder="Comment here ..." size="1" required id="id_body">
        </textarea>
      </td>
```

Or can do it with CSS too

```
   .form-group textarea{
      width: 300px !important;
   }/*width whatever you want*/
```

Comment: I have changed it to 20, and it doesn't work. Then I tried 10 and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Try with class  and add important-----    .form-group textarea{
      width: 300px !important ;
   }

Comment: That doesn't work. That 'form-group' is a bootstrap class.

Answer (score 0):

For a responsive CSS-Solution, you can set a maximum width, so that its also adapted on small devices:

```
.form-group textarea {
  width: 100%
  max-width: 400px; /*set maximum*/
}
```